# How to detect a hard restart (force restart) on an iOS device?

Tags: ios, xcode, appdelegate

I need to perform an action before the user force restarts the device.

I've thought of tracking how long a volume button is pressed, but that doesn't have to be the hard reset, so now I'm out of options.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to detect before a force restart. You need to save the user's data periodically (ideally, as they enter it).